# Maven shade plugin isn't placing dependency class files into jar

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse, maven-shade-plugin

My Maven project uses an external library as a dependency, `com.sk89q.intake:intake`, which I'm trying to package into my jar via the `maven-shade-plugin`. When building the project, the resulting jar does not contain any of the class files of `com.sk89q.intake:intake`. During the build process, I get this message, but the build continues on and succeeds:

```
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:2.4.2:shade (default) @ EventManagerPlugin
[INFO] No artifact matching filter com.sk89q.intake:intake
```

Why is this happening? I'm able to download, access, and use the dependency in my project, so there shouldn't be anything wrong with naming of the artifact.

**pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>deletethis.eventmanager</groupId>
    <artifactId>EventManagerPlugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-beta1</version>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spigot-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven.sk89q.com</id>
            <url>http://maven.sk89q.com/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
           <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
           <version>1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
            <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sk89q.intake</groupId>
            <artifactId>intake</artifactId>
            <version>4.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Built-By>deletethis</Built-By>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>com.sk89q.intake:intake</artifact>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>com/sk89q/intake/**</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.sk89q.intake</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>deletethis.eventmanager.lib.com.sk89q.intake</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

As you can see, I am including the `com.sk89q.intake:intake` artifact. I have looked through the `maven-shade-plugin` documentation and don't see what I'm doing wrong. The naming is consistent with everything I have found online; that is, `groupId:artifactId`.

I have also tried building without the `<relocation>` class relocation tags to see if they were interfering.

It may be useful to know that I'm using M2Eclipse and building with the `clean install` goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your are declaring the `com.sk89q.intake:intake` dependency with the `provided` scope.

Provided dependency are expected to be provided by the container at runtime so the `maven-shade-plugin` will not add it to your shaded jar. As such, you need to remove the `provided` scope from the dependency declaration:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sk89q.intake</groupId>
    <artifactId>intake</artifactId>
    <version>4.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Relevant build log after this change:

```
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:2.4.2:shade (default) @ test ---
[INFO] Including com.sk89q.intake:intake:jar:4.2-SNAPSHOT in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.0 in the shaded jar.
```